# consuming using @KafkaListener on a method.What are the means for me to keep track of how far along my Consumer is

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using Spring boot and specifically spring-kafka libraries for consuming from kafka.

I've a Class with @KafkaListener annotation on one of the methods to consume messages.I'm able to read in the messages. I realise its a topic and messages keep coming in based on the producer.
I want some kind of a cue that I'm at the last offset so I can trigger my re-conciliation logic with another source.How can I get hold of this cue.Is there a event that I can subscribe/listen to ?

Comment: Thx very much.It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the container `idleEventInterval` property and (each consumer thread) will emit a `ListenerContainerIdleEvent` when no records have been received during that interval.

Use an `ApplicationListener` or `@EventListener` method to consume the event(s).